# GridUnitType.Star?

Tags: c#, wpf

How does this star unit type works? I have read [msdn definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridunittype.aspx). But could not really get how it defines the size of an object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `*` sizes automatically adjust sizes proportionally. So, for example if you have a column with a width of `*` and another with a width of `*` then those two columns will have the same width (if they were the only two columns, that with would be 50% of the width of the grid).

If instead, one column was `2*` and the other `*` then the ratio of the widths of the columns will be 2:1. In other words, the first column will be 66% and the other would be 33%

If it was `4*` and `6*`, then the first column would be 40% and the second 60%. You could equally well write that at `2*` and `3*` because it's the ratio that's important, not the absolute numbers.